# Spotify IOS SDK Beta Ended playback of provider. Code=4 an unexpected NULL pointer was passed

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

Using the Spotify SimpleTrackPlayback demo and having trouble playing a track from my **Premium account** playlist or album.  I dummed it down to simply using the demo as is save for the required changes to urls and token exchange service.

The error I receive:
*Playback[69751:60b] Ended playback of provider spotify:album:4pT0rlFvHYc46KyEhmCy88 with error Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=4 "An unexpected NULL pointer was passed as an argument to a function." UserInfo=0x9948080 {NSLocalizedDescription=An unexpected NULL pointer was passed as an argument to a function.}*

From what I can see the playback never really starts as the delegate startPlayback event is never fired but the playback End delegate is fired regularly with the error above.  I have been stuck on this one for days but since i can't find much info on it I must be making a simple mistake somewhere.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I'm dealing with the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you're initializing the session correctly? With something like this:

```
self.session = [[SPTSession alloc]initWithUserName:username credential:cred];
```

Comment: When following the [beginners guide of Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/) the session is initialized by handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL and passed through to the callback.. So we have no control over how it is initialiazed

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me:

1. Go to **settings**
2. **Show advanced settings**
3. [image]